# How to check that user has entered the value which is listed in python list eg [1,2,3,4,5]

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, input

Eg.

```py
Mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

User_ip = 3
```

#user enters a value that is in the python list and if not print- not in the list

I am trying it with for loop but logic not works

```py
for i in Mylist:
    if i== User_ip:
        print ("value is in the list")
    else:
        print ("value not in the list")
```

Comment: Did you mean: `if User_ip in Mylist:`?

Comment: If you do as @quamrana suggested, you also don't need the `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Why not just check :

```
if User_ip in Mylist:
    print ("value is in the list")
else:
    print ("value not in the list")
```

Comment: Ooh yes i just don't needed for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a item is in the list with the `in` Operator:

```
Mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

User_ip = 3

if User_ip in Mylist:
    print("value is in the list")
else:
    print("value not in the list")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Input
Mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
User_ip = 3

if User_ip in MyList:
    print ("value is in the list")
else:
    print ("value not in the list")
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Ok i got it man...! Thank you what for loop did is list iterated in for loop and if else replaced the print statement with numbers